# Annoying Facebook popup (?) in browsers for a particular site

Tags: browser, popup

I do not know what to call these elements. Please see the attached image.

[image: Annoying popup window]

Every time I open a particular site (http://www.bdnews24.com/bangla/), this window appears at lower left. This is irrespective of Firefox or Chromium browser. Blocking popups did not help.

I can close this pest by clicking on the cross, but it will appear again in about five minutes. This a news site and it will refresh itself after a particular time. Since I read news regularly from this site, this auto refresh is a necessary feature for me.

Please tell me how do I stop these popups.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write a Chrome extension to disable it.

Comment: Is not there any ready made solution? I am not educated enough to write a chrome extension.

Comment: Move this to superuser, maybe?
EDIT: @MMA This is more suited to your question. http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://adblockplus.org/en/. It will not stop the popup, but it will stop the content within the popup.

Comment: Looks like adblockplus stops the content in main page as well.

Comment: In the filters section, try using just "AdBlock custom filters" and "EasyList"

Comment: It worked. Last time I did not configure the filters properly. Thanks.